# What are the differences between icon and button badges?

Tags: buttons, ios, html5, bootstrap, badge

iOS style badges are overlayed atop the upper right part of the icon. It's usually red with white text.

[image]

When displayed inline on a button or next to a header or link, IMHO, the badge seems to take on another role. The use of red feels more dangerous, or that there is something negative that requires my attention. The icon badge, although red, does not.

Is there any real difference, design-wise, that makes these two types of badges different or am I seeing things?

Comment: could you add screenshots to your question to highlight what exactly you are referring to?

Comment: Red doesn't always associate with danger. Rather, it means this needs attention. To really make something seem like a problem, you'd have to use association with icon, font weight and placement.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the red color has two points of view. One is used for *Dangerous*, another one is used for *Alert* or *Something Important* to see immediately. In these both are different. The Dangerous sign is mostly used with ***Exclamation mark (!)*** or Skull. But the *Important* sign is used with anything except these two signs.